# Plot excel data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How would I do to plot an excel file which consist of a set of data in two columns. Would like to make my first column data representing the y-axis and second column data in x-axis.

Comment: In Matlab type `doc xlsread` and `doc plot`. What you're asking is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Its really easy if you use the function `xlsread()`. Your code should look like

```
A = xlsread('Data.xlsx');
x = A(:,2);
y = A(:,1);
plot(x, y);
```